# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I have this error when i try to run my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    converter()
  File "C:\Users\Joan\Documents\School\Computing\Coursework\A453 - Python\Currency Converter.py", line 19, in converter
    exchange(currencyList)
  File "C:\Users\Joan\Documents\School\Computing\Coursework\A453 - Python\Currency Converter.py", line 33, in exchange
    crntItem = currencyList.index[crntCurrency] =+ 1
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment
```

Here is my code, an unfinished currency converter:

```
# Global ist
currencyList = ["Pound Sterling", 1, "Euro", 1.22, "US Dollar", 1.67, "Japanese Yen", 169.9480]



#################################
# A program to convert currency #
# Main function                 #
#################################
def converter():
    currencyList = ["Pound Sterling", 1, "Euro", 1.22, "US Dollar", 1.67, "Japanese Yen", 169.9480]
    print("1) Enter an amount to be exchanged.")
    print("2) Change exchange rates.")
    choice=0
    while choice==0:
        selected=int(input("Please select an option: "))
        if selected == 1:
            choice = 1
            exchange(currencyList)




#################################
# Giving exchanged rate         #
#################################

def exchange(currencyList):
    crntAmnt = int(input("Please enter the amount of money to convert: "))
    crntCurrency = ("Please enter the current currency: ")
    newCurrency = ("Please enter the currency you would like to convert to: ")
    listLength = len(currencyList)
    crntItem = currencyList.index[crntCurrency] =+ 1
    print(crntItem)
    newItem = currencyList.index[newCurrency] =+ 1
    print(newItem)
```

I have tried to set up a main function as a menu then call other sub - function to compltete the relevant choice. I would like some advice on whether this is a good and way to code this as I saw my teacher do something similar, of wether i should just put it into 'if' statements etc.

Is this a good, correct way to code?

Comment: What is the *full* traceback?

Comment: `currencyList.index[..]`, use `()` to call a function.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: and then there is the `=+ 1` after that, which is not valid Python syntax..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I noticed, for a while you included that invalid syntax in your answer as well. :p

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: shhhhh, you didn't see that, really.. :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currencyList.index` is a method reference; to index the list, drop the `.index` part:

```
crntItem = currencyList[crntCurrency]
print(crntItem)
newItem = currencyList[newCurrency]
```

I *suspect* you are trying to find the index of `crntCurrency` in the list, then add 1 to find the value instead:

```
crntItem = currencyList[currencyList.index(crntCurrency) + 1]
```

and

```
newItem = currencyList[currencyList.index(newCurrency) + 1]
```

but perhaps you should be using a dictionary here instead:

```
currencies = {"Pound Sterling": 1, "Euro": 1.22, "US Dollar": 1.67, "Japanese Yen": 169.9480}
```

This maps the currency name to a number, so now you can just look up currencies without having to fiddle around with indices:

```
crntItem = currencies[crntCurrency]
```

Oh, and you forgot to take actual user input; add `input()` calls when asking for the currency to convert:

```
crntCurrency = input("Please enter the current currency: ")
newCurrency = input("Please enter the currency you would like to convert to: ")
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @user3165683 here `crntCurrency = ("Please enter the current currency: ")` you forget the `input`